# disable ehcache on a particular field

Tags: ehcache, terracotta

In ehcache/terracotta, is it possible to disable caching only for a particular field/column and force to lazy load it from the database all the time.

We are having problems with one field which gets updated from the application not on terracotta and but terracotta is still holding old value. We need a means of disabling the cache on this particular field.

Below is the ehcache.xml entry for the query region used by the Query which still getting old value.

```
<cache name="query.users" maxEntriesLocalHeap="5000"
        eternal="true"
        maxElementsOnDisk="10000"
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU">
        <terracotta>
            <nonstop immediateTimeout="true" timeoutMillis="30000">
                <timeoutBehavior type="noop" />
            </nonstop>      
        </terracotta>
</cache>
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand : if one field on the objects is not cached, it means you'll need to make calls to the db for this one field - how would the cache help you then ?

Comment: can you add precisions on how you use Ehcache? Is it through Hibernate? What do you put in the cache?